# Having issues with a corrupt encryption error

Tags: python, encryption, io, pycrypto

Im trying to encrypt every line of the file test.txt the function encrypt() will output basically the text all jumbled up. For an end of year project in my computer science class. But my problem is when i try to run the code "backwards" with decrypt_all it doesnt work and the file is still corrupted

```
from Crypto.Cipher import XOR
import base64
import os

def encrypt(key=None, plaintext=None):
    if key == None:
        key = "This_is_my_hidden_key"
    cipher = XOR.new(key)
    return base64.b64encode(cipher.encrypt(plaintext))
def decrypt(key=None, ciphertext=None):
    if key == None:
            key = "This_is_my_hidden_key"
    cipher = XOR.new(key)
    return cipher.decrypt(base64.b64decode(ciphertext))


#####Run below to encrypt all files in folder and each sub folder#######

def encrypt_all(UselessVariable = None):
    root = os.getcwd()
    path = os.path.join(root, "targetdirectory")
    x=0
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
        for name in files:
            openfile = os.path.join(path, name)
            print openfile
            try:
                with open(openfile, 'r+') as a:
                    encrypted_text = []
                    for line in a:
                        encrypted_text.append(decrypt(None, line))
                    open(openfile,"w").close()
                    for text in range(len(encrypted_text)):
                        a.write((str(encrypted_text[text]))+ '\n')
            except IOError as e:
                print 'Operation failed: %s' % e.strerror
            x+=1
        print ""
    print x



#####Run below to decrypt all files in folder and each sub folder#######

def decrypt_all(UselessVariable = None):
    root = os.getcwd()
    path = os.path.join(root, "targetdirectory")
    x=0
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
        for name in files:
            openfile = os.path.join(path, name)
            print openfile
            try:
                with open(openfile, 'r+') as a:
                    encrypted_text = []
                    for line in a:
                        encrypted_text.append(decrypt(None, line))
                    open(openfile,"w").close()
                    for text in range(len(encrypted_text)):
                        a.write((str(encrypted_text[text])))
            except IOError as e:
                print 'Operation failed: %s' % e.strerror
            x+=1
        print ""
    print x
```

Comment: You're encrypting using the XOR cipher on a line-by-line basis, but decrypting all at once.

Comment: for the decryption im using
## for line in a:
         encrypted_text.append(decrypt(None, line))###
wouldnt that be line by line

Comment: But the encrypted text is all on a single line.

Comment: no its not the lines for encrypt automatically have a '\n' at the end

Comment: `encrypted_text.append(decrypt(None, line))`. That doesn't look right to me. In fact, I'm surprised it doesn't cause the encryption to fail with errors about being unable to decode the text.

Comment: uugh now its not working for me at all